# OAuth2AccessTokenResponseClient - Interface is blocking?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

The code-base I work with has a working OAuth model that uses OAuth2RestTemplate to manage access-tokens & access-token requests.  As OAuth2RestTemplate is deprecated, I want to move to Spring Security OAuth & WebClient.

When I looked at some of the classes involved, I was surprised to see that OAuth2AccessTokenResponseClient does not return a Mono, and the default implementation - DefaultPasswordTokenResponseClient - uses RestTemplate internally.

I thought one of the primary advantages of WebClient was that it was non-blocking? If that is the case, why is blocking I/O one of the default strategies for requesting access-tokens?  From the perspective of someone new to reactive/WebClient, I do not understand why the OAuth2AccessTokenResponseClient isn't itself a WebClient instance.

If I try to write a custom filter that uses WebClient to request the token, will I encounter major roadblocks or hard-to-detect bugs?  I do not have much knowledge to build off in this area but would still appreciate if someone could try to help out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are wrong a little: OAuth2RestTemplate is not deprecated; since Spring version 2.2.0 plenty classes are moved to new and other libraries, Spring left in OAuth module only the Authentication server, all other classes annotated as deprecated. OAuth2RestTemplate is used further, just with another package.

In light of this you can use RestTemplate further, but with changes in a project. Or, of course, to move to WebClient. This approach is not better or worse, it's just can work asynchronous and non-blocking.

We in our projects decided while not to move to new version, waiting for clear and fully understandable documentation about migration (at least last month it was not full and not fully understandable).